# 1-item asyncio queue - is this some standard thing?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, computer-science

In one of my asyncio projects I use one synchronisation method quite a lot and was wondering, if it is some kind of standard tool with a name I could give to google to learn more. I used the term "1-item queue" only because I don't have a better name. It is a degraded queue and it is NOT related to `Queue(maxsize=1)`.

```
#  [controller] ---- commands ---> [worker]
```

The controller sends commands to a worker (`queue.put`, actually `put_nowait`) and the worker waits for them (`queue.get`) and executes them, but the special rule is that the only the last command is important and immediately replaces all prior unfinished commands. For this reason, there is never more than 1 command waiting for the execution in the queue.

To implement this, the controller clears the queue before the put. There is no `queue.clear`, so it must discard (with `get_nowait`) the waiting item, if any. (The absence of `queue.clear` started my doubts resulting in this question.)

On the worker's side, if a command execution requires a sleep, it is replaced by a `newcmd=queue.get` with a timeout. When the timeout occurs, it was a sleep; when the `get` succeeds, the current work is aborted and the execution of `newcmd` starts.

Comment: It sounds like queue is not the primitive for your use case, though you somehow made it work. I'd implement such synchronization with a pair of `asyncio.Event` to which I'd attach the command you need to run. That way you don't need to clear anything, just assign the new command and you're done.

Comment: @user4815162342 Could you please write more details about the pair of Events? I'm sorry, but I did not get what you mean by that.

Comment: Sorry, the "pair" was leftover from an edit, and referred to the pair of (event, command), command being the object you now put in the queue. It later occurred to me that you can attach the command to the event (using an ordinary assignment, `event.my_command = ...`, so you don't need to carry two objects around. Does this help?

Comment: @user4815162342 Let's see. The controller sets the `my_command` attr and calls `event.set`. The worker - when awakened - fetches the command and calls `event.clear`. Yes, I think that should work. An `Event` is a simpler concept, but does not solve the data exchange, the command must be attached to it. OTOH a `Queue` transfers the data, but have to be used in an unusual way. Not sure if I should change my program, but your idea helped me to see the issue from another angle. Thanks.

Comment: Correct, that's exactly what I had in mind. You don't really need a queue, just a wakeup mechanism and a cell for the single object to attach to the wakeup (latest command). Event is the simplest multi-use wakeup device in asyncio (there's also condition, but it adds complexity from multithreading that you don't need at all). And if you use event, don't forget to call `event.clear()` from the worker immediately after `event.wait()`, otherwise the event will remain set. Don't worry about race conditions since a coroutine can't switch between awaits.

Comment: I found a difference between a `Queue` and an `Event` based implementation. If there is a worker pool, in the latter case all waiting workers are awakened by a single command. I understand that it makes little sense to have a worker pool and only 1 valid command at a time, I just want to leave this here noted as a remark.

Comment: Good point - for added safety the workers could check whether the event is actually set. BTW if the issue is resolved, I can write an actual answer (that will include this remark) - StackOverflow comments can disappear and are not meant for useful content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of queue you are using is not standard - there is such a thing as a one-shot queue, but it's a different thing altogether.

The queue doesn't really fit your use case, though you made it work with some effort. You don't really need queuing of any kind, you need a slot that holds a single object (which can be replaced) and a wakeup mechanism. `asyncio.Event` can be used for the wakeup and you can attach the payload object (the command) to an attribute of the event. For example:

```
async def worker(evt):
    while True:
        await evt.wait()
        evt.clear()
        if evt.last_command is None:
            continue
        last_command = evt.last_command
        evt.last_command = None
        # execute last_command, possibly with timeout
        print(last_command)

async def main():
    evt = asyncio.Event()
    workers = [asyncio.create_task(worker(evt)) for _ in range(5)]
    for i in itertools.count():
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        evt.last_command = f"foo {i}"
        evt.set()

asyncio.run(main())
```

One difference between this and the queue-based approach is that setting the event will wake up all workers (if there is more than one), even if the first worker immediately calls `evt.clear()`. A queue item, on the other hand, will be guaranteed to be handed off to a single awaiter of `queue.get()`.

Comment: Note that this code relies heavily on the cooperative rather than preemptive nature of asyncio - both `main` and `worker` have critical sections protected by nothing more than the fact that there's no `await` in the critical section. This wouldn't work in threading without explicit locks.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Correct - but that's typical of asyncio programming, not really specific to this code. For example, `await evt.wait()` followed by `evt.clear()` is idiomatic with asyncio events and would fail miserably with multi-threaded events.